# Customise Windows 10 File Explorer short-cut menu

Tags: windows-10, copy, contextmenu, customization, explorer

Don't suppose anyone can help?  I frequently publish single files from my test website to the live one, and would love to be able to right-click on a file (or use a keyboard short-cut; I'm not fussy) and choose a custom menu option saying something like "Copy to Owly Production Folder".

[image]

What I know already:

1. There's a way to edit the registry to add the MOVE TO and COPY TO commands to the right mouse button context menu.  This wouldn't solve my problem, as I'd still then have to choose which folder to move/copy to.
2. That you can add things to the Send To menu shown pictured above by adding items to the relevant Windows folder.

I know how to write a DOS batch file (I'm that old) and also to write .NET programs - I just don't know how to launch a program, and how to detect the currently selected file in Explorer.  I don't know PowerShell and would prefer not to learn, but suspect that if there is an answer it involves this.  If so, so be it.

I'm using Windows 10 by the way.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I've got this to work for a folder, but not for a file.  The stages are:

1. Create a console app project in Visual Studio (or any other development environment!).
2. Write code to copy the file (or folder's files).
3. Build this project.
4. Create a short-cut for it in the **Send To** folder.

When you right-click on a folder you should now be able to send this to your application, which should copy the contents of the folder.  Some notes on the above follow ...

When creating your app, the **args[0]** argument holds the file path or folder path that you've just right-clicked on.  So you can get at this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // get path of file to copy
        String sourceFolderPath = args[0];
```

An easy way to go to the **Send To** folder is to type this into the File Explorer address bar:

[image]

When you right-click on a file or folder, you should see something like this:

[image]

However, if you write in your program to copy the single file that you've just right-clicked on, you get an error saying it's in use.  Presumably "sending a file" locks it.  I couldn't find any way round this, so I modified my program so I could right-click on a folder, rather than a file.

Anyone else able to solve this final problem?

Answer (score 0):

My english  is not good but I will try to help you out.  You can directly add your application in the registry location:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell

Then create a key:

CopyFiles

And another key inside:

command

The result will look like:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\CopyFiles\command

In the command key the (Default) add your application path as it points to your app:

"c:\folder\anotherfolder\VSProjects\CopySelectedFileArg.exe" "%1"

When you right click any file type you will get the option to directly open with your app. Let let us assume you have a form app, in the program.cs you add:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    string fileName = null;
 

   
        fileName = args[0];
       


        Application.Run(new Form1(fileName )); 
}
```

and in the form1:

```
string filePath;
string DesPath =@"d:\a\b\";
        public Form1(string fileName)
            : this() 
        {
            filePath= fileName;
string TheFileName=Path.GetFileName(filePath); 
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
           
      if (Directory.Exists(DesPath))
            {
                
             fi.CopyTo(DesPath + TheFileName, true);
           
              }
        }
```

You will not have an error for copying one or multiple files, just make sure your destination directory exists.  You can have a timer that will close the app or just click close yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this out some time soon when I get time (and courage to alter the registry!).  I've edited your text just to tidy up the English a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send a file to a folder here is what you do
1 Create folder
2 Right click --> Copy
3 Go to SendTo folder (something like C:\Users\PC\SendTo)
4 Paste shortcut

and that's it.

You may be blocked from the SendTo folder with an "Access Denied" error in which case you need Right click - Properties - Security - Advanced - Change Owner.